# Error while installing angular CLI - cb() never called

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, npm-install

I am facing an issue - continuously trying to install angular CLI globally. Can anybody please help what could be the possible answer to resolve this issue?

We can see that whenever I tried to install It shows install successfully but when I run command ng new project name it stuck a long time at installing packages and give me the following error although new project runs successfully.
[image]

Comment: try re-installing nodejs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run command npm i -g npm@latest
2. Run command npm i -g @angular/cli@latest